# Hiding PHP / MySQL error message

Tags: php, mysql, webserver, x-cart

I have a website based on [X-Cart](http://www.x-cart.com/). It’s working fine. However, when I go to the address (manually accessing the link) `www.mysite.com/"Xx<XaXaXXaXaX>xX` I get this error message:

> **INVALID SQL:** 1064 : You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '",)`'
>   LIMIT 1' at line 1<br /><b><font color="darkred">SQL QUERY
>   FAILURE:</font></b>SELECT xid FROM xcart_session_history WHERE ip =
>   INET_ATON('165.193.42.141') AND host = '&quot;XxxXx';&quot;,)`' LIMIT
>   1
> **INVALID SQL:** 1064 : You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   ';",)`', 'e8bc1df13aab2c25c7560512a5029eb1')' at line 1<br
>   /><b><font color="darkred">SQL QUERY FAILURE:</font></b>REPLACE INTO
>   xcart_session_history (`ip`,`host`,`xid`) VALUES
>   (INET_ATON('165.193.42.141'), '&quot;XxxXx';&quot;,)`',
>   'e8bc1df13aab2c25c7560512a5029eb1')

I find this to be a vulnerability on my system because it reveals the table name and other details.

I would like to keep PHP/MYSQL from showing this message on the screen. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `$debug_mode` in config.php to 2

http://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Config.php#Correcting_debug_mode

Answer (score 2):

// Turn off all error reporting

```
error_reporting(0);
```

// Report all PHP errors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

// Report all PHP errors

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

use any of that one if you use database then select error_reporting(0)

Answer (score 1):

To turn off all error reporting:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

You should set it at top of some header file that is loaded across all pages.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a message generated automatically by PHP(mysql-errors usually will not be printed).

Answer (score 0):

`error_reporting(0);` //is **safer** then modifying the **config.php** file